# .NET Owin Authentication using my own userRepository

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, token, owin

I am creating a new Web API and using OAuth2 for token authentication and UnityResolver for DI. At this moment i am having some degisn questions about how to use my own userRepository to authenticate users. I've been reading lots of articules this two days, the solutions i mainly found are implementing the IStoredUser, IUser.. for this case i think there would be a better fit. 
This my codes :

```
 public class OAuthServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    IUserAccountService _userAccountService;

    public OAuthServerProvider(IUserAccountService userAccountService)
    {
        _userAccountService = userAccountService;
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        var ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;

        var user = await _userAccountService.GetUserByLogin(context.UserName, context.Password, 1, userAgent, ipAddress);

        if (user != null && context.UserName == user.email && context.Password == user.password)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", user.email));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.firstName));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

as you can see i'm using IUserAccountService to authenticate if an user exists in my database by calling a stored procedure and dapper to invoke the SP, at this part i'm okay. The problem occurs when i need to instantiate this class in my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    internal IUserAccountService _userAccountService;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {             
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);  

        var oAuthProvider = new OAuthServerProvider(_userAccountService);

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = oAuthProvider
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
}
```

I will get a null object reference because of the IUserAccountService, i tried to inject it into the startup class constructor, but it won't work.

Do you have any idea how to implement this solution by using good practices and DI ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have defined your `IUserAccountService` to be per request lifetime scope.
This way the `IUserAccountService` is instantiated at the begining of a web request.
The `Startup.Configuration()` method is executed when the oauth server is launched and there is no web request at this moment.

I got into a similar problem but I use Autofac and solved it getting the Autofac lifetime scope from the OwinContext:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    ...
    // Get IUserService from AutofacLifetimeScope (e.g. 'AutofacWebRequest')
    var autofacLifetimeScope = OwinContextExtensions.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(context.OwinContext);
    var userService = autofacLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserService>();
    ...
}
```

This way you get the `IUserService` instance from the web request lifetime scope.

I don't know if you can do something similar with Unity.

I hope it helps.